# How to join tables with duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, join, unique

I have two tables. One include all the demographic information for customers(Table1)  and the other include the purchases data(Table2).
The one with purchase data has multiple rows for each id.
To find the demographic data for each customer I need to join two tables, how should I fix the bellow query?
※each tables has more than 10 columns

```sql
select distinct *
from Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: If all you want is the demographic data then why `JOIN` to `Table2` at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want the data not to be duplicated, you can select the specific field that is not unique, like this: `select distinct t1.name, t1.address from ...`
Hope this article [distinct](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) can help,